# How to search by Number format in ListView Data in android

Tags: android, listview, android-contentprovider, contacts, android-contacts

[I am New of android,i m working by contacts,,,I am completed search by text but I want search By number Format in android][1]

public class ContactFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

```
RequestQueue requestQueue;
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;
private ArrayList<SelectUser> selectUsers;
private List<SelectUser> temp;
private ListView listView;
Cursor phones, email;
// Pop up
ContentResolver resolver;
private EditText search;
private ContactAdapter adapter;
private View myview;
int count=0;

private ArrayList<String>server_PhoneNum;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactslayout, container, false);

    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    server_PhoneNum = new ArrayList<>();

    search = (EditText) myview.findViewById(R.id.editMobileNo);
    selectUsers = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
    resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    listView = (ListView) myview.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
    // Read and show the contacts
    showContacts();

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            adapter.filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    return myview;
}
private void showContacts() {
    // Check the SDK version and whether the permission is already granted or not.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
    } else {
        // Android version is lesser than 6.0 or the permission is already granted.
        List<SelectUser> contacts = getContactNames();
      adapter=new ContactAdapter(contacts,getActivity());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
private List<SelectUser> getContactNames() {
    List<SelectUser> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    // Get the ContentResolver
    ContentResolver cr =getActivity().getContentResolver();
    // Get the Cursor of all the contacts
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

    // Move the cursor to first. Also check whether the cursor is empty or not.
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // Iterate through the cursor
        do {
            // Get the contacts name
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phone_number=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String Image=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));

            SelectUser user=new SelectUser();
            user.setName(name);
            user.setPhone(phone_number);
            user.setThumb(Image);
            contacts.add(user);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // Close the curosor
    cursor.close();

    return contacts;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is granted
            showContacts();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Until you grant the permission, we canot display the names", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to type number then give `android:inputType="number"`.Otherwise your previous answer is common for number and text. `android:inputType` will allow only which type of input you wants to give.

Comment: sorry I want search By contact Number

Comment: I have Some Contacts in Listview I am completed the search By name But I want search By number